# Add an IE 8 Only JavaScript to the Orchard CMS head element

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, razor, orchardcms

I would like to add the Bootstrap-recommended shims to the Orchard CMS `head`. Usually, I would add the following.

```
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Is this the Orchard way to add IE 8 only JavaScript to the `head`?

- If yes, how do we add comments to the Orchard CMS `head` from the Layout.cshtml view?
- If no, how do we add IE 8 only JavaScript to the Orchard CMS `head`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine `@Script()` with `AtHead()` and `UseContition()`.

This is a quick, Orchard way to add the Bootstrap-recommended shims, for IE 8 only, to the Orchard CMS `head`.

```
Script.Include("//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js")
    .AtHead()
    .UseCondition("lt ie 9");

Script.Include("//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js")
    .AtHead()
    .UseCondition("lt ie 9");
```

This [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142925/how-to-use-javascriptjs-file-in-orchard-cms) discusses `@Script` and this [Orchard Issue](http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20118) mentions the `UseCondition`.