# Multiple Javascript calls on an Orchard field

Tags: javascript, orchardcms

I'm creating a module that allows users to see the status of a set of IP addresses by creating a custom field that holds the address (and validates it when it's first entered). On the Field view there's a glyphicon that changes based on the result of a ping attempt.

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NuyX.png)

However, I'm having difficulty in getting the Javascript for pinging the address and each individual field to pass arguments correctly. For some reason, only the address from the first field is passed to the Javascript, instead of using the addresses from each individual field.

[How it looks when only one address gets passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfgD1.png)

I've checked the page with Firebug and found that the onload arguments are collected and sent correctly, but the Javascript is only receiving the first field's contents. Since the Javascript uses the arguments to determine which DOM to change, only the first DOM is ever altered.

I've also confirmed that the values are passed incorrectly by making the spanIDHolder and addressHolder spans visible and having the Javascript alert with the contents of those two spans. The HTML displays the correct value, but the alert only shows the first.

Here's the code for the view:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
@{
    string ipaddress = Model.ContentField.Value;
    string spanID = ipaddress + "span";
    bool showPingResult = Model.ContentField.ShowPing;
}
<body>
    @{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipaddress)) {
            if (showPingResult) {
                <span id="addressHolder" style="display:none">@ipaddress</span>
                <span id="spanIDHolder" style="display:none">@spanID</span>
                <span id="@spanID">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </span>
            }
            <span class="text-field">@ipaddress</span>
        }
    }
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var address = document.getElementById("addressHolder").innerText;
        var id = document.getElementById("spanIDHolder").innerText;

        function setPingResult() {
            var elem = document.getElementById(id);
            elem.innerHTML = '<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"></div>';
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setPingResult();
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

The Javascript is temporarily simplified until I can get the parameters passing correctly, so 'address' is unused.

Things I've tried so far:

- Other methods of including the Javascript code such as inlining or including it in the HTML as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142925/how-to-use-javascriptjs-file-in-orchard-cms)
- Doing the ping through a C# function and using if statements on the view to display the correct symbol

  - This works, but means that it runs the ping script before the page loads. If there's a way to call the C# function in the onload block (or equivalent), that would be a solution
- Running the code through an onload call on the body and storing the Javascript in a separate file
- Moving things around randomly hoping it decides to work

Let me know if I need to provide code from elsewhere in the project.

Edit: Some things I've found so far...

The block at the beginning which designates the variables is only executed once, no matter how many individual fields are on the page. I found this by replacing spanID with the output of a random number generator. All four fields received the same random number.

I've tried encasing the field in a part, but can't figure out how to get the variables to the part view instead of the field view. A viewmodel may be the key?

The variables can be passed to the Javascript section just by using @ in front of the needed variable name. This results in the *last* field's data being passed.

Comment: I think this happens because the `addressHolder` and `spanIDHolder` spans have the same id for every field. Your javascript gets exectued four times, once for each field, but `document.getElementById("addressHolder")` will always get the first element on the page with that id. If you make sure the ids are unique it will probably work. I advise you to create a template for the Part instead of the Field though and loop through all of the spans in there. That way, all of this code only gets included once in the page.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Did you have any luck with the info on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766870/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-a-field-to-a-custom-part-in-code)?

Comment: As far as I can tell it's currently not possible to exactly control the position of fields added through migration. That's not exactly related to your problem though. You should be able to render the editor for your part in `Views/EditorTemplates/Parts/MyPart.cshtml` like in the example here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part/#getting-the-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

For some reason, the pass works correctly if I collect the variable in the document.ready block instead of directly in the JS function. Therefore, instead of

```
function setPingResult() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('@spanID');
    elem.innerHTML = '<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"></div>';
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setPingResult();
});
```

I use

```
function setPingResult(spanID) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(spanID);
    elem.innerHTML = '<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"></div>';
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setPingResult('@spanID');
});
```

If someone could explain *why* this works, that would be lovely.

Comment: It's because your @spanID is in the global scope when you call it outside of $(document).ready(). That causes all of the instances of Javascript to only look for the first spanID variable they come across. Encasing the entire script in a self executing anonymous function fixes the scope issue.

Comment: And if you're really competent, you should actually be doing this using a Script.Include tag, then a for loop on all objects on the page with a specified class, rather than using GUIDs for HTML tags.